Windows 11 + RDP in full screen: Local taskbar pops up when pointer moved to bottom
I was just upgraded to Windows 11.  I RDP to a machine on the same LAN and work with the RDP in full screen.  When I move the pointer to the bottom of the screen, the local taskbar pops up.  This is not what happened when I was on Windows 10.  How can I control this, i.e., disable and enable it?  I looked through the RDP options but didn't see any controls that looked relevant.
Afternote:  I only seem to see this behaviour on some days or half days.  For example, the behaviour wasn't present this morning, but has emerged this afternoon. I didn't quit RDP and reconnect today, but I do use a KVM switch flip over to computer other than the one from which I am running RDP.

I see this issue all the time, and I fully understand your frustration. I would be surprised however to find that there is a setting that could change that behavior. Seems more like a bug than something intentional. I'll be checking back to see if anyone has any brilliant ideas!

When you say that you see this all the time, do you mean specifically with Windows 11 and RDP?

yes. RDP session from Win11 to another windows system (probably always win11).

Thanks for clarifying.  In my case, I RDP from Win 11 machine to Win 10 machine, still seeing the same behaviour.

Does using windows key + T bring up the correct taskbar? Does it depend on how far you move the mouse off the bottom of the screen?

Honestly, I don't know which "correct" taskbar, but I want to disable the popup local taskbar for now.  I may want to get that behaviour in the future.  However, the popup behaviour is not repeatable.  I don't see it today, no matter what I do with the pointer.  Yesterday, if I move the pointer to the bottom edge of the desktop, the local taskbar pops up.
